# Is there a finite abelian category?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, abelian-categories

> Is there a non-discrete abelian category which has only finitely many objects?

Just out of curiosity I am wondering if such an abelian category exists, while the usual examples of abelian categories that I know contain infinitely many objects.

If the finiteness is too strong a condition, then per chance one might ask

> Is there an abelian category whose objects form a set?

I have no idea whether such a *small* abelian category exists; I am not even sure if the set of all abelian groups exists.

**Edit:**

Thanks to @Oskar, this question already has an answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111965/are-there-any-nontrivial-abelian-categories-with-only-finitely-many-objects). But I cannot mark this question as duplicate, as that is a math overflow question.

As a brief summary, @Jeremy Rickard gave an answer there: there is an abelian category with two objects, which is any skeletal category of the quotient category of the category of countable dimensional vector-spaces by the Serre subcategory of finite-dimensional vector-spaces.

---

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: The category of all finite-dimensional $k$-vector spaces is an abelian category; so a skeleton of this category, e.g. consisting of $k^n$ for $n \in \mathbb N$, is a set-sized abelian category.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So then the question remains for the finiteness!

Comment: My intuition says no, but I don't know enough to make it formal. Note that if $X$ is any object, you also need $X \oplus X \oplus \cdots \oplus X$ in the category. You could choose $X$ with $X \oplus X = X$, so that you only get finitely many objects -- like picking $X = \mathbb Z^{\oplus \omega}$. Of course such an $X$ is then quite complicated, and it seems like you should get infinitely many quotients from it....

Comment: For set-sized abelian category, you should read about the embedding theorem from Freyd. It will interest you and you will read examples which will help you in your question. A good reference is the Handbook of Categorical Algebra, of F. Borceux, just read the last section of the first chapter of Volume 2.
For finiteness, my intuition was the same as Mees de Vries. So I believe it will be complicated, but one should try to construct an example.

Comment: @Sov Thanks for the recommendation of the book. I knew the embedding theorem, but I am not requiring the category to have set-sized hom, just set-sized Ob. I will have a look at the book later. Thanks again.

Comment: If there is a set of all Abelian groups, what would be the product of all these groups, if not an Abelian group which is larger than any group in the set?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, without knowing what I know about cardinalities, it would seem to be that it could be a group which is already in the set -- certainly there are sets of groups for which the product of each group in the set is already in the set (up to isomorphism, anyway).

Comment: @Mees: Right. Then take the power set of that group, as an Abelian group with symmetric difference as addition. But you're right that some basic knowledge in set theory is needed. But why is that a bad thing? :)

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111965/are-there-any-nontrivial-abelian-categories-with-only-finitely-many-objects

Comment: The category with exactly one object and exactly one morphism is Abelian and finite. In fact, this is the only Cartesian Closed Abelian category, up to unique isomorphism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To put this question off the unanswered-list:

The question got an answer on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111965/are-there-any-nontrivial-abelian-categories-with-only-finitely-many-objects) by Jeremy Rickard:

> "Take the category of (at most) countable-dimensional vector spaces over your favourite field. Then take the quotient by the Serre subcategory of finite-dimensional vector spaces. (And take a skeletal subcategory so that it strictly has only two objects.)
>
> Then this is an abelian category with only one non-zero object, whose endomorphism ring is the endomorphism ring of a countable-dimensional vector space, localized at the set of endomorphisms with finite-dimensional kernel and cokernel."